# MQMessageProducer takes time on send

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have a server which is publishing changes to 3rd party MQ queue using the MQMessageProducer. Basically in my publisher I am looping over the list of messages and call the producer's send method to publish messages to the queue. Normally it works fine but sometimes with a big batch it takes more than 30 sec to send the messages and I need it to do this in less than 30 sec.

Here is how I setup the JMS connection and publication flow:

- Setup the connection and session using MQQueueConnectionFactory at
  the sytem start-up.
- For each batch of messages to be published,

  - create the queue and then the Producer.
  - Loop over list of message string and send using producer.

From the logs, it takes few milli-seconds to acquire the producer but then the send takes more than 30 sec to publish around 400 messages to the queue.

I tired to look for a sequence flow of the MQProducer send but couldn't find much. Can someone explain how the MQProducer works?

Is there something wrong in the flow or any way I can make sure to never go more than 30s?

Comment: How many ms is the server you send to in a ping?  How large are each message. Remeber that each MQ client action is sending and receiving from the server, so you have a round trip for every message. For example: client puts a message, server acknowledges the message.  Does the order of messages matter?  Could you create multiple parallel producers?

Comment: server ping ms -> I need to check. 
Each message is between 3kb to 10kb, with most of the time <5kb.
Yes order of the message matter, so I cant have parallel producers.

Comment: Do you have info on the queue you PUT to on the queue manager?  Does it have `DEFPSIST(YES)`?  Is it a `QLOCAL` or a `QREMOTE` or something else?  Is your total publish time for a smaller number of messages correspond?  Ex: if you send 200 messages does it take 15 seconds?

Comment: I dont have access to the setting/config of the MQ server. From my logs what I saw is that except this one time, every other batch load which had even more messages than 466, was done is between 5 to 10 sec. This particular one more than 33 sec.

Comment: Are you using a Transacted session?  This can help with performance if the queue you put to has default persistence turned on: DEFPSIST(YES).  Other than that I do not have any other suggestions with out knowing more details.  If it was one time, then I would just monitor it to see if it happens again.